# Eclipse is showing an error that is not real?

Tags: eclipse, exception

Today, I was working on a Minecraft mod in Eclipse, and my computer had to restart, and it force closed Eclipse. Now when my computer restarted, I errors I had previously fixed were highlighted. The code was fixed and ran perfectly fine, but Eclipse still pointed out my "errors" at the point where they were before.

[image: eclipseIsAmazing]

I have tried refreshing the workspace, restarting Eclipse, and any of the generic troubleshooting techniques. Any tips would be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you clean the project (Project->clean) and do a build? Also manually close the editors and reopen them...

Comment: I get these every now and then and if the generic techniques you mentions don't work try to remove the code and then put it back exactly how it was.

Comment: @Nivas Thank you, I didn't know about the cleaning option. That worked exactly as I needed it to. Can you make an answer out of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you clean the project (`Project->clean`) and do a build?

Comment: Note: Might not actually be a real error marker.  See my comment below.

Comment: @TehHippo Yes, your solution would work well also, but Nivas' was exactly what I needed. (+1 for you though)

Answer (score 3):

Try cleaning the build folder (usually  bin) manually or by Project -> Clean command, deselecting automatic build and then rebuilding the whole project.

After that it should be right and you can re-enable the automatic build feature.

If that doesn't work you could also try to delete the project (not from disk) and re-import it into the workspace.

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly how it is done. But if you don't mind, can I give the Accept to Nivas if he makes an answer? (He answered first with the same explanation)

Answer (score 1):

1. Delete the error from 'Markers'
2. Run a 'Refresh'
3. Run a 'validate' over your project.